How to conditionally format non-adjacent cells in Microsoft Excel based on the second highest value
I am preparing a scorecard for a quiz to be played among 6 teams. A part of which looks like the following:

The cell with the highest score is highlighted in Green. I achieved this using an inbuilt formula under "Conditional formatting" on the cells D4, D10, D16, D22, D28 and D34. What I want more is to highlight the second and third highest scores as well. I am facing great difficulty in achieving that because of the non-adjacency of the cells.
I tried plentiful efforts with the LARGE function, but it refuses to accept an array as input and expects a range instead.
I think at this point I should mention that I am using Microsoft® Excel for Mac with a 365 subscription. My machine is running macOS Sonoma. In my failed efforts I suspected that LARGE is usually accepting arrays as inputs in Windows machines.
One more point to emphasise is that I do not want to discard duplicate values in the mentioned cells. I have a tiebreaker rule in the quiz if the multiple total scores become equal.

Could there be ties? How to behave then? What have you tried? Untested: =let(n,{4;10;16;22},d,index(D:D,n),XLOOKUP(LARGE(d,2),d,n)=row())

In case of a tie, it should format all the tied cells with the same formatting. My primary try: Select the mentioned cells -> Conditional formatting -> New rule -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format -> =D4=large({D4;D10;D16;D22;D28;D34},2).  This produces the message "There's a problem with the formula."

Following the same path, "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" -> your formula produces`You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges), array constants, or the LAMBDA function for Conditional Formatting criteria.

In a separate cell, your formula produces the result "FALSE".

=D4=large(vstack(D4,D10,D16,D22,D28,D34),2) ?

No luck yet. With all values set as 0, it is formatting all cells, however with non-trivial values, it is not working!

But you said ties should highlight all

Do we need to show each rank in different color?

@P.b, please let me know, if my answer needs correction or improvement. Thank you.

@P.b Yes, but it is doing that only with the values all set to 0. With values 15, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, it is not highlighting anything.

Conditionally Format Non-Adjacent Cells According to Ranks

Select D4:D34 and add the following 3 conditions:
=IF(ISNUMBER(D4),RANK.EQ(D4,D$4:D$34)=1)
=IF(ISNUMBER(D4),RANK.EQ(D4,D$4:D$34)=2)
=IF(ISNUMBER(D4),RANK.EQ(D4,D$4:D$34)=3)


What's with the ISNUMBER()?

It takes care of not formatting all the irrelevant cells when 0 is among the top three.




The screenshot illustrates a way to build and test the formulas. The cells E4:G4 contain the same 3 formulas.
You can copy/paste all of it horizontally (to the right or left) because only the rows are locked ('$').
Since you cannot avoid locking rows, to copy vertically (down or up), you need to copy/paste to the right then cut/paste down or up and copy horizontally as you see fit.


With 0 among the values, it looks like both RANK.EQ and LARGE treat blank cells as having 0.
So, could you try
Minor update 2024-08-25

Select the range, D1:D20 in the example
Add new rule - "Cell contains blank values" - no format - set "Stop if true"
For testing the ranking, you could use the following, for example in J1
=RANK.EQ($D$1:$D$20,$D$1:$D$20)
as seen in the screenshot.
You can see that cells with zeros and blank cells are assigned the same rank; though blank cells are assigned same rank as cells with zero, the subsequent ranking is not affected by it.
With D1 highlighted, clear conditional formatting and set as the new rule

For different color for each rank,
=(RANK.EQ(D1:$D$20,$D$1:$D$20) = <1, 2 or 3>)




Thank you for your effort. However, it is considering the positive and negative values but not 0. First of all, let me mention about a little inconsistency in your formulas between the text and image representations. In text, you wrote IF(...$E$20) <= 3), however, in the second image, it mentions IF(...$E$20) = 3). Anyway, I tried both of them producing same incomplete results. With the values 10, 10, -5, -5, -10, -10; it highlights 4 cells in green and red correctly. Nevertheless for the set 10, 10, 0, -5, -10, -10; it stops only with two green cells.

It worked for me (just typed in 10,10,0,-5,-10,-10 not the whole table and set three rules)

@SubhajitPaul, you're right about result is not correct with 0s. Please let me know if the updated answer works.

Thank you @TomSharpe for testing. I wasn't aware of how RANK.EQ and LARGE work with a range containing both zeros and blanks.
